# friend.toLowerCase is not a func. error when applying ionic's searc function

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I get this error "friend.toLowerCase" is not a func. error when applying ionic's searc function. The only thing that is different in my program, is that I dont have only a list of JSON items, but a list with 5 items per Item, like `friend.name`, `friend.status`, e.t.c. I changed a few things, e.g. Ionics list was called items, mine friendsList. I think the error might be caused by confusing names. But I didn't find the mistake.

HTML

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getFriends($event)"</ion-searchbar>
...
<ion-item *ngFor="let friend of friendsList">
...
<h2>{{friend.name}}</h2>
...
```

TS

```
 export class RankfriendsPage {
      friendsList;

     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
       this.initializefriendsList();
  }

  initializefriendsList() {
    this.friendsList = [
     {
          "name": "Alice",        //list example
          "status": "Online",
          "img": "img/6.jpeg",
          "img2": "img/33.jpeg",
          "text": "+ADD"
        },
    ];

      }




       getFriends(ev) {
          // Reset items back to all of the items
          this.initializefriendsList();

          // set val to the value of the ev target
          var val = ev.target.value;

          // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
          if (val && val.trim() != '') {
            this.friendsList = this.friendsList.filter((friend) => {
              return (friend.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
            })
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because there is no friend object with the function toLowerCase(), i guess you need ,

```
 this.friendsList = this.friendsList.filter((friend) => {
    return (friend.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
friend = {
  "name": "Alice",
  "status": "Online",
  "img": "img/6.jpeg",
  "img2": "img/33.jpeg",
  "text": "+ADD"
}
```

As you can see there's no `toLowerCase` property there.

If you wish to use it, use it on a string, such as `friend.name`.

Answer (score 1):

**Friend** is an object and objects don't have toLowerCase() property.

You can apply toLowerCase() to strings only.

you can use friend.status.toLowerCase() , friend.name.toLowerCase() and etc.